# Error: Native deployment method is supported since version 7.1 Jboss

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss

I am configuring IntelliJ to run my Jboss 7.1 remotely, which is on a linux Ubuntu 18.4 in my machine(I'm using WSL).

When I try to deploy my .ear file and set staging option to native IntelliJ throws me this error:

> Error: Native deployment method is supported since version 7.1 Jboss

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Hows does the server configuration look like in the IDE? I'd recommend [submitting a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) with the logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data) and all the details as it would be more convenient to continue in YouTrack. Share the screenshots with all the Run/Debug configuration tab and the application server configuration (directory, jars, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You just have remove the JBossServer and put it on again, that will work it out